# jQuery ajax request giving error : undefined

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, ajax, cordova

I'm trying to recieve data in JSON from online php code, I'm getting undefined error
The website i'm retrieving from is https://www.orba.com.ng/getemployees.php

I'm using jQuery

```
localStorage['serviceURL'] = "https://www.orba.com.ng/";
var serviceURL = localStorage['serviceURL'];

var scroll = new iScroll('wrapper', { vScrollbar: false, hScrollbar:false, hScroll: false });

var employees;

$(window).load(function() {
    setTimeout(getEmployeeList, 100);
});

function getEmployeeList() {
    $('#busy').show();
    $.getJSON(serviceURL + 'getemployees.php', function(data) {
        $('#busy').hide();
        $('#employeeList li').remove();
        employees = JSON.parse(data.items);
        $.each(employees, function(index, employee) {
            $('#employeeList').append('<li><a href="employeedetails.html?id=' + employee.id + '">' +
                    '<img src="img/' + employee.picture + '" class="list-icon"/>' +
                    '<p class="line1">' + employee.firstName + ' ' + employee.lastName + '</p>' +
                    '<p class="line2">' + employee.title + '</p>' +
                    '<span class="bubble">' + employee.reportCount + '</span></a></li>');
        });
        setTimeout(function(){
            scroll.refresh();
        });
    });
}

$(document).ajaxError(function(event, request, settings, thrownError) {
    $('#busy').hide();
    alert("Failed: " + thrownError.error);
});
```

I'm getting error code undefined

Comment: Before ajax call press **F12** then navigate to `console` tab , read js errors

Comment: Suspect it's a CORS issue.

Comment: Also, you should not have to `JSON.parse()` your items, it should al l already be JSON data.

Comment: @Twisty I ran the request using Postman and data is being set as `text/html` instead of `aplication/json` so that's why...

Comment: Also, `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header is `*` so that's OK.

Comment: Could you convert this to a JSFiddle please @Kunle? Make sure to include the HTML code JS is manipulating... http://www.jsfiddle.net

Comment: Nothing ever just says _"undefined error"_. What **exactly** is the error message? Provide screenshots of your console if you cannot translate it well to text

Comment: Please how should i change it to application/json? @danielperaza

Comment: @twisty thanks its a CORS issue

Comment: You don't need to @Kunle. Did you figure this out already? If not, please create a JSFiddle like I said before...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a CORS issue, Quite easy to fix. Search on google